# How do I read a text file and make it into a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary in Python from a text file.

The text file is given like the following:

```
Name,birthday,deathdate
Alan,Jan6,Dec12
Jovi,Oct6,Feb6
Kyle,June4,May9
```

The first line has all the keys and the next few lines are values that map onto those keys in order. The expected result is a dictionary where the name and birthday and deathdate are keys and the values map onto the birthdays.

```
{
    Name:[Alan,Jovi,Kyle],
    birthday:[Jan6,Oct6,June4],
    deathdate:[dec12,feb6,may9]
}
```

So, how would I create a dictionary like so?

Comment: Hey guy. This is a CSV file. Look at the `csv` package.

Comment: more specifically, the [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) object

Comment: What's the expected result? "values that map onto those keys in order" is quite vague.

Comment: the expected result is a dictionary where the name and birthday and deathdate are keys and the values map onto the birthdays. 
So: {Name:[Alan,Jovi,Kyle],birthday:[Jan6,Oct6,June4],deathdate:[dec12,feb6,may9]}

Comment: @BorisLai I don't wanna be "that guy," but are you SURE you want that? It seems like a REALLY difficult data structure to use..

Comment: @AdamSmith ye im sure I want that data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are reading from a csv file Named `in.txt`. First you read all the lines from file and store them in a list. Then you should create an empty dict. Then we assign a empty list to each item in first line. Then we iterate all other lines and append them to their respective lists.

```
L = []
with open('in.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.strip().split(',')
        L.append(l)
M = {}
for key in L[0]:
    M[key] = []
for i in range(1,len(L)):
    for j in range(len(L[i])):
        M[ L[0][j] ].append(L[i][j])
print M
```

Output:

```
{'deathdate': ['Dec12', 'Feb6', 'May9'], 'birthday': ['Jan6', 'Oct6', 'June4'], 'Name': ['
Alan', 'Jovi', 'Kyle']}
```

Comment: I am trying to make Name birthday and deathdate the keys. So all the following lines are values and the first line are keys. Also, I am reading from a .csv file.

Comment: This is really ugly. Lots of single-letter variables (what is an `L`? What's `i` and `j`?) We should be using the `csv` module.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want that output, then try:

```
import csv

with open("yourfile.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(reader)
    lines = list(reader)

result = dict(zip(headers, zip(*lines)))
# {'birthday': ('Jan6', 'Oct6', 'June4'),
#  'name': ('Alan', 'Jovi', 'Kyle'),
#  'deathdate': ('Dec12', 'Feb6', 'May9')}
```

`zip(*some_list)` is a useful idiom to convert rows to columns. Here we use it to pair header names with their columns.

Do note that this creates tuples, not lists, in the resultant dictionary. If you need lists instead, you'll have to coerce them yourself in a dictionary comprehension

```
result = {header: list(values) for header,values in zip(headers, zip(*lines))}
# {'birthday': ['Jan6', 'Oct6', 'June4'],
#  'name': ['Alan', 'Jovi', 'Kyle'],
#  'deathdate': ['Dec12', 'Feb6', 'May9']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to install `pandas` this can be done in one line:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt').to_dict("list")
```

Output:

```
{'Name': ['Alan', 'Jovi', 'Kyle'],
 'birthday': ['Jan6', 'Oct6', 'June4'],
 'deathdate': ['Dec12', 'Feb6', 'May9']}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the data is in the text file 'data.txt':

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> my_dict = pd.read_csv('data.txt').to_dict('list')
>>> my_dict
{'Name': ['Alan', 'Jovi', 'Kyle'],
 'deathdate': ['Dec12', 'Feb6', 'May9'],
 'birthday': ['Jan6', 'Oct6', 'June4']}
```