# create dictionary from text file with headers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file test.txt

```
col1|col2|col3
1|a|123
2|b|456
```

I want to create a python dictionary with column as keys and respective values as values in python.

Comment: Could you give us the dict you want for your example?

Comment: Include desired output and a coding attempt. Sounds like a jobs for `csv.Dictreader`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a text file and make it into a dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010534/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-and-make-it-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {}
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[int(key)] = val
```

Alternatively, if you are running python 2.7, you can use [Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {}

read = open("test.txt")
for l in read:
        l = l.split("|")
        dict.update({l[0]:l[1:]})
print(dict)
```

it works

Comment: Sorry but i am getting below output after using this code:                     
{'col1': ['col2', 'col3\n']}
{'col1': ['col2', 'col3\n'], '1': ['a', '123\n']}
{'col1': ['col2', 'col3\n'], '1': ['a', '123\n'], '2': ['b', '456']}

Comment: I am expecting a output like {col1:[1,2]]} {col2:[a,b]} {col3:[123,456]} Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:

```
read = open("test.txt")
a=[]
for z in read:
    a.append( z.split("|"))
dict = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i == 0:
        for j in a[i]:
            dict[j] = []
    else :
        for j in range(len(a[i])):
            dict[a[0][j]].append( a[i][j])
print(dict)

output: {'col1': ['1', '2'], 'col2': ['a', 'b'], 'col3\n': ['123\n', '456']}
```