# convert txt into dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a txt file has a header of 10 keys, with more than 1000 rows of both strings and numerics, and I want to read them and do some analyses in dictionay format. (I try some codes I can search, they will either said too many values to unpack, or not enough values to unpack. )

for instance the txt file could be like:

```
name age city job food ... address
Amy 26 London lawyer fish ... WE09KT
...
Lisa 30 LA teacher egg ... LY76SU
```

I want the output to be like a dictionary:

```py
[{name: Amy,age: 26,city: London,...}{name: Lisa, age: 30, ...}]
```

some ask me to visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010534/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-and-make-it-into-a-dictionary-in-python), but the output will be *`{'name age city job ... address':['amy ... lisa','26 ... 30',...]}`* which is not what I want. (yes I don't even know what I even didn't get what the link shows: a return like *`{name:[Amy, ..., Lisa],age:[26,...,30],...}`*), could anybody also tell me the reason?

thanks for the help again, hope this clarify and could reach the answer!

Comment: You may want to read the Markdown Editing Help, particularly the one for [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). The file format you are using is more commonly known as a CSV file. It's common to use the reverse of your current index notation, e.g string2.3 is row 2, column 3.

Comment: this question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010534/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-and-make-it-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read a text file and make it into a dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010534/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-and-make-it-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: i try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010534/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-and-make-it-into-a-dictionary-in-python but the return is different from what they said. Mine will be {'key1 key2 ... key10':['string1.1 number2.1 ... string10.1','string1.2 number2.2 ... string10.2'...'string1.10 number2.10 ... string10.10']}

Comment: It's not really worth an answer here, but look at the answer already mentioned, then look at the manual for the library they use here https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html and you will see there is a `delimiter` parameter which you can change from comma to space

Comment: If your delimiter is a single whitespace then `import csv` and do `with open("file.txt", "r") as file: result = list(csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=" "))`. Maybe you have to adjust `delimiter` and/or add `skipinitialspace=True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`.readlines`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-python/) and then [combine](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary/) the first line with every other line with [`zip`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) to form each dictionary in **`dict_list`** below:

```py
input_fp = 'x.txt' ## set the path to the ACTUAL file
sep_str = None # ' ' # ',' # ' | ' # '\t' # 

with open(input_fp) as f:
    # text_lines = [l.rstrip() for l in f.readlines()] # keep empty lines
    text_lines = [l.rstrip() for l in f.readlines() if l.strip()] ## no empty lines

dKeys = text_lines[0].split(sep_str) if text_lines else [] 

maxSplits = len(dKeys) - 1
dict_list = [dict(zip(dKeys, tl.split(sep_str,maxSplits))) for tl in text_lines[1:]]
```

- You can also use `f.read().strip().splitlines()` instead of *`f.readlines()`* and omit the *`if l.strip()`* part if you want to skip whitespace at the beginning but still represent empty lines later on with empty dictionaries (`{}`).
- Use `l.strip()` instead of *`l.rstrip()`* if you might have spaces at the beginning of lines that you need to ignore.
- Omit `maxSplits` if you don't want to mash the last "word"s together if a line has more "word"s than in the fist line. For example, if your file contains <kbd>*`'k1 k2 k3\nv1 v2 v3 v4'`*</kbd>, then

  - as it is above, it would be converted to **`[{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3 v4'}]`**
  - but if you only used

    ```py
    dict_list = [dict(zip(dKeys, tl.split(sep_str))) for tl in text_lines[1:]]
    ```

    then the resulting `dict_list` would be **`[{'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}]`** (i.e., `v4` would be cropped out instead of being tacked onto `v3`)
- About the `sep_str` value that will be used to [`.split`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split) each line into values:

  - `sep_str=None` --> *`'v1  v2 v3'.split()`* would return **`['v1', 'v2', 'v3']`**
  - `sep_str= ' '` --> *`'v1  v2 v3'.split(' ')`* would return **`['v1', '', 'v2', 'v3']`**

---

For an example, if your file contained

```py
First_Name Last_Name Gender Age Phone Occupation
Penelope Miller Female 23 069-5515-87 Teacher
Julian Watson Male 19 355-0427-79 Cook
Gianna Barnes Female 27 641-6494-91 Mechanic
Walter Walker Male 28 164-8407-47 Mechanic
Chelsea Scott Female 28 272-2601-10 Florist
```

then the resulting `dict_list` should be:

> ```py
> [
>   {'First_Name': 'Penelope', 'Last_Name': 'Miller', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Age': '23', 'Phone': '069-5515-87', 'Occupation': 'Teacher'},
>   {'First_Name': 'Julian', 'Last_Name': 'Watson', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': '19', 'Phone': '355-0427-79', 'Occupation': 'Cook'},
>   {'First_Name': 'Gianna', 'Last_Name': 'Barnes', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Age': '27', 'Phone': '641-6494-91', 'Occupation': 'Mechanic'},
>   {'First_Name': 'Walter', 'Last_Name': 'Walker', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': '28', 'Phone': '164-8407-47', 'Occupation': 'Mechanic'},
>   {'First_Name': 'Chelsea', 'Last_Name': 'Scott', 'Gender': 'Female', 'Age': '28', 'Phone': '272-2601-10', 'Occupation': 'Florist'}
> ]
> ```

Comment: There is no need to use `f.readlines()`,  `f` is already an iterator.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful and easy to follow!!